# IF IF IF como fazer? PHP IF com erro de sintáxe

Tags: php

No código, são várias condições, de acordo com as escolhas do usuario. 
O sistema é simples, apenas verifica se o usuário pode ou não receber seguro desemprego.
Estou seguindo a tabela:

[image: Tabela seguro]

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
<?php   

$tx = 2;
            /* Exibe o resultado caso a variável possua um valor diferente de null */
            if ($tx !== null): 

                if($pedido == primeira):

                    if($meses >= 12 && $meses <= 23):
                        $parcela = "4";
                    elseif($meses > 23):
                        $parcela = "5"; 

                elseif($pedido == segunda):

                    if($meses >= 9 && $meses <= 11):
                        $parcela = "3";
                    elseif($meses > 11 && $meses < 24):
                        $parcela = "4"; 
                    elseif($meses > 24):
                        $parcela = "5";

                    endif;    
                endif;

            endif;
```

Está dando o erro:

> ```
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in > C:\wamp\www\extudando.esy.es\teste.php on line 24
> ```

e não tem nada na linha 24

Sei também que a sintaxe deve estar errada (tipo funciona, mas é gambiarra), mas não consegui pensar em uma maneira mais "correta". Como poderia corrigir isso?
Ou o unico jeito seria IF IF IF mesmo ? E não consigo corrigir o erro

Comment: Substitua `$meses => 12` por `$meses >= 12`. Isso acontece pois `=>` é utilizado para atribuir um valor a um índice do Array, por isso o PHP acusa o erro.

Comment: `endif` leva `;` a fechar. Convem rever a sintaxe da linguagem sempre que tiver duvidas.

Comment: Após a edição... Falta uma variável em `&& <=23`, o correto é `&& $variavel <=23`.

Comment: `$parcela = ` também não pode ficar dessa forma.

Comment: Corrigi isso mesmo Isac ! Completei, e corrigi a ordem do =< .... mas agora dá o erro:

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\extudando.esy.es\rh_seg-des.php on line 62

Comment: @Flávia O correto é `<=` e não `=<`. Recomendo a leitura http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Corrigi, recriei, ainda assim consta algum erro na sintaxe, e não sei o que estou fazendo errado

Comment: @Flávia há dois erros em seu — novo — código. 1) É necessário envolver as palavras `primeira` e `segunda` por aspas ou adicionar o `$` e transformá-las em variáveis; 2) Falta um `endif;` antes de `elseif($pedido == segunda):`

Answer (score 0):

- Falta um `endif` veja comentário no código
- primeira e segunda, devem estar entre aspas simples
- Tem que decidir o que acontece quando numero de meses é igual a 24

  ```
      if ($tx !== null): 

          if($pedido == 'primeira'):

              if($meses >= 12 && $meses <= 23):
                  $parcela = "4";
              elseif($meses > 23):
                  $parcela = "5"; 
              //faltando no seu código
              endif;

          elseif($pedido == 'segunda'):

              if($meses >= 9 && $meses <= 11):
                  $parcela = "3";
              //deve ser <=24 ?
              elseif($meses > 11 && $meses < 24):
                  $parcela = "4"; 
              //ou deve ser >=24 ?
              elseif($meses > 24):
                  $parcela = "5";
              endif; 

          endif;

      endif;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Na primeira parcela está faltando o endif

```
if($pedido == primeira):
  if($meses >= 12 && $meses <= 23):
     $parcela = "4";
  elseif($meses > 23):
     $parcela = "5"; 
 endif; // aqui
```

2. Nesse caso você espera o usuário escrever 'primeira' ou 'segunda'? Sugiro você colocar um menu com números indicando as opções: 1- Primeira Parcela 2- Segunda parcela.
   O usuário precisará digitar apenas o número referente a opção, e não a palavra inteira.
   Além disso, é necessário adicionar aspas simples nas condições, pois a entrada do usuário é em formato de string

`if($pedido == 'primeira')` ou `if($pedido == '1')`